# LWC: Any idea if Custom Events will be filtered in the future releases?

Tags: lightning-web-components, gtm, custom-event, customevent

I am trying to implement GTM(google tag manager) with a community following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/04/google-tag-manager-for-community-cloud.html) article.

The problem I am experiencing is that GTM cannot see the lightning web components that were loaded in the community page. To solve this I am firing [CustomEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) which bubble up all the way up to GTM(being loaded in the markup header) and that is working fine.

However I couldn't find anything about `CustomEvents` and if Salesforce plans on controlling the way those propagate in the future.

**EDIT**

Providing some code as a reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="outter-wrapper">
    <div onclick={chatClick}></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
chatClick() {
    if (this.template.querySelectorAll('.outter-wrapper')[0]) {
        let chatEvent = new CustomEvent(
                    'chatEvent',
                    {
                        detail: {
                            startChat: true
                        },
                        bubbles: true,
                        cancelable: true
                    }
                );
        this.template.querySelectorAll('.outter-wrapper')[0].dispatchEvent(chatEvent);
    }
}
```